# selenium webdriver test is stopped by browser idle warning window

Tags: java, firefox, browser, junit, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to automate the Login module for an application (https://*************.com) in my project. One of the feature of this site is, if this site is opened in a browser and kept idle for more than 10 minutes and then try to Login - Error window will be displayed stating:

> Browser is kept idle for more than 10 minutes. For security reasons close the current window and try to login in new window.

But when I try automate the application, above Error window is displayed as soon as i submit the login form(that is upon entering Username and Password). In the same browser if I manually enter details and try to Login, it's working perfectly.

I'm using Java Junit for automation in Firefox and I don't have admin rights on the system in which I'm doing it.

I tried in Internet Explorer too. I was able to override security certification at the beginning, but before page load, user account control window panel is displayed to enter admin username and password (which I don't know). if I click "No" (in user account control) selenium test case will continue. but upon submission different error is displayed stating "java applet is completely not loaded. wait for some time".

So, I'm stuck at the login without any progress. Please help me out to know what could cause that error while login.

Below is the code used to automate it:

```
  @Before
  public void Enter() {
      driver.get("https://************.com");
  }

   @Test
  public void EnterDetail() {
    driver.findElement(By.id("username").sendKeys("AAAAAAA");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password").sendKeys("BBBBBBB");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login").click();
  }

  @After
  public void Close() {
    driver.quit();
  }
```

Comment: Your code seems pretty straightforward. Without having access to your site, I do think anyone will be able to help you. Check with your developer(s) to see if they can suggest something.

Comment: Hi SiKing, the code for tha application is more than 8 years old and few enhancements will be done in each release. This site is developed by different companies so I'm not sure whom to contact. I'll try to get some information with current developers.

Comment: One more thing, before you get too deep into this. You mentioned the error about java applet. If your tests need to interact with the applet, Selenium is **not** a good choice.

Comment: oh ok SiKing. Thanks for the info. I'm contacting developers to find a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a code problem. You're missing closing paren.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("your id").sendKeys("aaaaa");
```

is wrong.  you need to close your paren before .sendKeys(); see below

```
driver.findElement(By.id("my I'd")).sendKeys("Aaaaaa");
```

Comment: Hi bacar, Sorry for the typo error in the code. Even after adding paren, the same issue persists.

Comment: If you inspect the dom are the elements youre attemtping to interact with in an iframe? If they are you need to swith to that frame. driver.switchTo().frame("id of frame"); // then do your work above // then switch back. driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

Comment: I checked it, they not using iframe for that login page.

Comment: Whats the html look like?